# Mongodb and PHP $and query

Tags: php, mongodb

the following query is not working for me in PHP, I need help finding out what is wrong with it, I have check other examples and still don't know how to fix it...

```
$query = array(
    "Client"        => $notificationJob['Client'],
    "Email"         => $notificationJob['Email'],
    "Backup Type"   => $notificationJob['Backup Type'],
    array ( "$and"  => 
        array(
            array( "Message Subject" => new MongoRegex('/'. preg_quote($notificationJob['MessageSubject string1']). '/i') ),
            array( "Message Subject" => new MongoRegex('/'. preg_quote($notificationJob['MessageSubject string2']). '/i') )
        )
    ),

    "Time Stamp"    => array('$lte'=>New Mongodate($startDate->getTimestamp()))
);
```

The error I am getting is:

Notice: Undefined variable: and in ...

thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `'$and'`.  Variables in double-quotes are interpolated.

You could also use `"\$and"`